# Smart folders and Enterprise Keywords

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, modern-experience, enterprise-keywords

I have a simple to describe but seemingly hard to resolve problem in SharePoint Online 365.

I have a library with a lot of folders and subfolders, and in these folders are located documents. I started tagging them with Enterprise Keywords in order for my users to search them more easily.

My next step is to be able to create smart folders (or views), for example: a folder called "Strategy", in which all documents located in my subfolders tagged with the Enterprise Keyword "Strategy" appearing in it.

I tried creating a view that filters on keywords, but the folder remains empty.

I'd be very glad to hear from you if you have any idea, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to display all documents (Including those inside the subfolders) with a filter on the Enterprise Keyword column, you can edit the view for this.

We only need to set the filter on the column, just like you has done, and set it to **Show all items without folders**. In this way the view will not displaying folders, only shows all the documents meeting the criteria you set on filter.

It is a view setting in the folder part.
[image]

And it works like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good start! I see one limitation though: I'd like to create a folder that does not contain files and folders, and populate it with all the tagged files I have in the library which are located in other folders.

The solution you propose is neat, but I can't use it to aggregate files from folders and subfolders that are not contained by the folder in which I am setting the new View, or maybe am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you have an idea for this? I tried on my side but no luck... Thanks again!

Comment: @Spigaw, you can create the view at the top-level of the library. If you need to create a ,like you say smart folder to hold all these files with certain tag, I think it is not doable in SharePoint Online Out-of-box.